# Have a div moving (dynamicly) with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, position

Is it possible with css to have a div move with the screen while the user is scrolling (e.g. fixed) 
but then stopt if it hits another one and jump over it if the user scrolls further.

To make it imaginable...
for example if you have  3 divs  with a lot of text is it possible that i have  div jumping into slots under each of those as the user reads forward?

Comment: Yes.  It's possible.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: He probably lacks basic javascript knowledge so he can't try anything... except reading some javascript tutorials.

Comment: Very nice comment Ivan ;)   but partly true... i usually adjust ready script to fit rather then knowing it. therefor i know a lot of other things. JS it none of them yet.

Comment: For the other question - the on that might bring this topic further -  i tryed only, and  was  searching for CSS solutions  unitl  now.
The  idea that JS could do it just came while  i  was wirtig  the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps and then do something like this to slot the moving div:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var movingDiv = $('.moving-div');

    if (movingDiv.overlaps('.static-div') 
            && !movingDiv.hasClass('slotted')) {
        $('.static-div').before(movingDiv);
        movingDiv.css('position', 'static');
        movingDiv.addClass('slotted');
    }
});
```

The code is just a hint and you also need to bind a function for "unslotting" the moving div.

Answer (score 0):

Make the math using a transparent dummy object that have the same propierties than the fixed one.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var b1_fo = $("#dummy").offset().top + $("#dummy").height();
    var b2_fo = $("#b2").offset().top + $("#b2").height();
    if( b1_fo > $("#b2").offset().top && b1_fo < b2_fo + $("#dummy").height()){
        $("#b1").css({top:$("#b2").offset().top - $("#b2").height(),position:'absolute'})
    } else {
        $("#b1").removeAttr('style')
    }
})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LpULy/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps and then do something like this to slot the moving div:

The code is just a hint and you also need to bind a function for "unslotting" the moving div.

I hope this would be helpfull
Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).